# Get the minimum innerWidth of a floated element sibling

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-float

Trying to solve one really tricky problem here. Hope you guys can help.

The situation is as follows: we have a floated picture, and an adjacent P element, that obviously aligns itself to the left. The problem is, that from a position point of view, the element still takes the full width. Which makes sense for the part that comes after the image, but not so much for the text "But I must explain..." which is on top.

Here is an image that illustrates the problem:
http://postimg.org/image/65r9v8qyz/

Now trick question: is there any way to get the innerWidth of the beginning of the element? boundingClientRect and getComputedStyle didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: buddy, I don't know which elements you are talking about! please mention your design code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element is being floated, it's going to display over or under another element. You're not going to be able to get the innerWidth directly.

What you can do is take the innerWidth of the P(paragraph), then minus the innerWidth of the image from that(as well as any padding/margins/borders/other that might add to the image element's width). This should give you something reasonably accurate though tricky to manage and deal with.

Code example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var imageElement = document.getElementById('IMAGE_ID_HERE');
    var paragraphElement = document.getElementById('P_ID_HERE');

    var topWidth = paragraphElement.innerWidth - (imageElement.innerWidth /* Add any padding, etc. to this */);
});
```

Comment: nice answer though, but as without code a question is not helpful to others.. so the answer as well!

Comment: thanks. very creative approach. will probably give it a shot!